# org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: Connection timed out

Tags: java, spring

Issue : In below code we are invoking external application through restTemplate exchange method.

What is happening is for starting few requests it is getting response and after that it is throwing `org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: Connection timed out` exception.

Code:

```
resp = restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.POST, request, Response.class);
```

Stack Trace :

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: Connection timed out (Connection timed out); nested exception is java.net.Connect
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:453)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:377)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
```

Comment: A time out could occur for any kind of reason, mainly because of a network problem. Are you using the right target host and port? Do the receiving machine has some sort of firewall? etc

Comment: I don't think so.. If it is network issue then it should not allow any requests ryt?..

In my case for first few requests I am getting response after that it is throwing above error